# How to create method that take the keyof interface as an argument, and the arguments of the function excluding the first

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## the title seems too long but sees my example.

#### I have this interface

```
interface Types {
    string: (value: string, letterAllowed: string[]) => boolean;
    number: (value: number, maxNumber: number) => boolean;
}
```

#### and this object which uses the interface

```
const types: Types = {
    string: (value: string) => typeof value === "string",
    number: (value: number) => typeof value === "number",
};
```

#### and i have this class with this interface

```
interface Check {
    test(type: keyof Types, ...args: any): boolean;
}

class Check {
    value: any;

    constructor(value: any) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    test(type, ...args) {
        return types[type](this.value, args);
    }
}
```

#### what I want is this.

```
// show error, you need to pass key of "Types"
new Check("value").test("");

// show error, you need to pass the maxNumber argument
new Check(5).test("number");
// no errors
new Check(5).test("number", 10);

// show error, you need to pass the letterAllowed argument
new Check("value").test("string");
// show error, letterAllowed is array of strings not number
new Check("value").test("string", [1, 2, 3]);
// no errors
new Check("value").test("string", ["a", "b", "c"]);
```

#### what I have tried so far is this.

```
interface Types {
    name: (value: string, letterAllowed: string[]) => string;
}

type ParametersExceptFirst<F> = F extends (arg0: any, ...rest: infer R) => any ? R : never;

interface Check {
    <K extends keyof Types>(value: K): Types[K];

    <K extends keyof Types>(value: K, ...args: ((R & ((arg0: any, ...rest: R[]) => any)) | never[])[]): boolean;
}

const check: Check = (value: any, ...args) => {
    return true;
};

// [✅] it shows an error if you don't pass any key of "Types"
check("");

// it doesn't show an error if you didn't pass the second argument
check("name");

// [✅] it shows an error if you pass an array of different types instead of a string
check("name", [1, 2, 3]);
```

#### what I want is how can I improve what I build and use it with a class method

## Edit

#### the solution works but when I add it to class

```
interface Types {
    string: (value: string, letterAllowed: string[]) => boolean;
    number: (value: number, maxNumber: number) => boolean;
    boolean: (value: boolean) => boolean;
}

const types: Types = {
    string: (value, letterAllowed) => typeof value === "string",
    number: (value, maxNumber) => typeof value === "number",
    boolean: (value) => typeof value === "boolean",
};

type OmitFirstArgument<T> = T extends (first: any, ...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

class Typeof {
    value: any;

    constructor(value: any) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    is<T extends keyof Types>(type: T, ...args: OmitFirstArgument<Types[T]>): boolean {
        return types[type](this.value, ...args);
    }
}


new Typeof("sss").is("number",10);
```

#### it shows this error

```
return types[type](this.value, ...args);
```

> TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

#### i manage to solve that by using apply

```
return types[type].apply(this, [this.value, ...args]);
```

#### add string as another option to use with keyof Types

```
class TypeOf<T> {
    value: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    // TODO
  // TS2536: Type 'A' cannot be used to index type 'Types'.
    is<A extends (keyof Types | string)>(name: A, ...args: OmitFirstArgument<Types[A]>) {
        return types[name as any].apply(this, [this.value, ...args]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `infer` keyword. It can help you in these cases

```
interface Types {
    string: (value: string, letterAllowed: string[]) => boolean;
    number: (value: number, maxNumber: number) => boolean;
}

type OmitFirstArgument<T> = T extends (first: any, ...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

const doStuff = <T extends keyof Types>(name: T, ...args: OmitFirstArgument<Types[T]>) => {};

// No error
doStuff('number', 123);

// No error
doStuff('string', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'u']);

// Error - string isn't number
doStuff('number', 'hello');

// Error - number[] isn't string[]
doStuff('string', [1, 2, 3]);

// Error - expected 2 args, but got one
doStuff('string')
```

The issue you outlined above is weird, and code is giving me weird results in the type inferences. To solve it, you can use type coercion:

```
interface Types {
    string: (value: string, letterAllowed: string[]) => boolean;
    number: (value: number, maxNumber: number) => boolean;
    boolean: (value: boolean) => boolean;
}

const types: Types = {
    string: (value, letterAllowed) => typeof value === 'string',
    number: (value, maxNumber) => typeof value === 'number',
    boolean: (value) => typeof value === 'boolean',
} as const;

type OmitFirstArgument<T> = T extends (first: any, ...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

class TypeOf<T> {
    value: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    is<A extends keyof Types>(name: A, ...args: OmitFirstArgument<Types[A]>) {
        // Coerce
        return (types[name] as Types[keyof Types])(this.value, ...args);
    }
}

new TypeOf('hi').is('number', 5);
```

Comment: thanks dude u are the best

Comment: @Meslzy you are <3

Comment: sorry I'm very hasty, it's working that's why I accept it, but I couldn't make it work with class

Comment: @Meslzy Could you clarify what you're trying to do with the class? It's unclear

Comment: u can see my edit, maybe u got something better than my solution, but thanks anyway as I said u are the best 

Comment: @Meslzy check my edit

Comment: It's exactly like what I did, but I got another issue which is I want to add a way to let users type in a key that even if not exists in the interface. see my edit.

Comment: @Meslzy Why would you want them to type a key that doesn't exist? `types['foobarbazblah']` is uncallable and will result in an error.